# HTML canvas: Rotating and translating an image to fix a point in image to coordinates in canvas

Tags: canvas

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XEYEKd

**Problem**: Given a scene rendered on one canvas, what transformations do I need to apply to cause a point on the first canvas (x1,y1 are known) to be at some fixed point on the second canvas (x2, y2 known, but relative to second canvas, not relative to first) after a rotation is applied to the image/scene of canvas 1.

See the codepen above for a playground to work with.  Try to get the red point to be, say, centered in the viewport.  Manipulate the rotation (the `degrees` variable) and `p.x` and `p.y` to be arbitrary values, and test if your transformation code still works (to keep the red point in the middle of the viewport).

I've tried a bunch of things applying sin, cos, inverse sin, inverse cos, and the Pythagorean Theorem, but have not had any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to define the source coordinates you'll use in `drawImage`.

These coords are the negative values of your point's coords + half the size of your destination canvas, so that the point is drawn in the center of the destination canvas wherever it was on the source canvas.

Once you've got it, all you have to do is to apply the basic

```
translate(center, center);
rotate(angle);
drawImage(img, -center, -center);
```

```js
function draw() {
  const scene = document.getElementById('canvas-scene')
  const ctx1 = scene.getContext('2d')
  const viewport = document.getElementById('canvas-viewport')
  const ctx2 = viewport.getContext('2d')
  const p = {
    x: (Math.random() * (ctx1.canvas.width - 20)) + 10,
    y: (Math.random() * (ctx1.canvas.height - 20)) + 10,
  };
  const radians = (Math.PI *2 * Math.random());

  let img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/images/sibley_shillinglake_nc.jpg'

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    ctx1.fillStyle = 'red'
    ctx1.fillRect(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
    // get destination width and height
    const cw = ctx2.canvas.width,
      ch = ctx2.canvas.height,
      // new coords are the negative of our point coords + half the width of our new canvas
      newX = (p.x * -1) + cw/2,
      newY = (p.y * -1) + ch/2;
    // move to canvas center
    ctx2.translate(cw / 2, ch / 2);
    ctx2.rotate(radians);
    // draw by translating back to the top left corner
    ctx2.drawImage(scene, newX - cw/2, newY - ch/2);
  }
}
draw();
```

```css
#canvas-viewport {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Viewport</h3>
<canvas id="canvas-viewport" width="256" height="128"></canvas>

<h3>Scene</h3>
<canvas id="canvas-scene" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

Comment: I arrived at a working solution independently of you, but I see that yours works, so I'll give you an upvote and an accept.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Koeoxd

Turns out no trigonometry was needed at all.

```
function draw() {
  const scene = document.getElementById('canvas-scene')
  const ctx1 = scene.getContext('2d')
  const viewport = document.getElementById('canvas-viewport')
  const ctx2 = viewport.getContext('2d')

  let img = new Image();
  img.src = 'http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/images/sibley_shillinglake_nc.jpg'

  const p = {
    x: 150,
    y: 200,
  }

  img.onload = function () {
    ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0)
    ctx1.fillStyle = 'red'
    ctx1.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 10, 10)

    const degrees = 60
    const radians = (Math.PI / 180) * degrees

    ctx2.translate(viewport.width/2, viewport.height/2)
    ctx2.rotate(radians)

    const imgX = -p.x
    const imgY = -p.y
    ctx2.drawImage(scene, imgX, imgY)
  }
}
```

(@Kaiido gave me a good solution at the same time.  His solution also takes into account adjusting to get the exact center of the red point on the map, something I didn't bother to do yet.)